# Error while importing datasets from sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
```

it gives the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/songoku/PycharmProjects/untitled/sklearn.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
  File "/home/songoku/PycharmProjects/untitled/sklearn.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn import datasets
ImportError: cannot import name 'datasets'
```

Comment: As @MaxU answered, rename your script's name to anything else. `sklearn.py` shadows the original `sklearn` package and hence you cannot import any of the modules from it.

Answer (score 1):

Rename `/home/songoku/PycharmProjects/untitled/sklearn.py` to something that differs from the SKLearn module name: `sklearn.py`

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the version of sklearn first. The modules like data-sets and svm is not a part of sklearn packages (0.19 <) i.e less than version number 0.19.0.

You can check this on the command line: pip3 list

it shows you the version of all libraries installed by pip3.

Note: Always double check if you istalled the libraries as a part of anaconda or pip3